# how to display social icons on cv instead of url in php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I'm creating a cv page and it has social media section like in image below :
[image]

I created an auto add input so user can add social media profile url as much as they want.

Example :
if user has 3 social accounts (can be more) inputs will become like so as array :

```
<input type="text" name="social[]" id="social" placeholder="social"/>
<input type="text" name="social[]" id="social" placeholder="social"/>
<input type="text" name="social[]" id="social" placeholder="social"/>
```

And I insert them into database like this in one column:

```
$social = implode(',', $_POST['social']);
```

They look like this in database :

```
https://twitter.com/username,
https://www.facebook.com/username,
https://username.tumblr.com/,
```

**Question**

How can I check and replace url coming from database with the correct icon of that website ?
like this :

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $facebook; ?>" title="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $twitter; ?>" title="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $tumblr; ?>" title="tumblr"><i class="fa fa-tumblr-square"></i></a>
```

I'm stuck on it. I realy need your advices, my brain stopped working.

Thanks for all helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code it manually, while retrieving social links of relevant user from database, read every link and find which social account is it about.

```
If (stristr($linkFromDatabase, "https://facebook.com")){
     // This link is about facebook and icon will be facebook icon
}

If (stristr($linkFromDatabase, "https://twitter.com")){
     // This link is about twitter and icon will be twitter icon
}
```

Add same for every social accounts possible.

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work for some pages like `https://username.tumblr.com/` which has username in subdomain part. I think I need to do something in html part, but dont have a clue what to do :(

Comment: Don't match full string, just a part of the string, like find the Facebook or FB word in linkFromDatabase, not like matching it completely.

Comment: you mean this `If (stristr($linkFromDatabase, "twitter")){` or use regex ?

Comment: Exactly, but this may give false results in future. If any Facebook or tumbler user get the username like xyztumblr then it will create problem. So always match like ```if(stristr($linkFromDatabase, "facebook.com"))``` always add .com suffix.

Comment: If find this answer useful then mark my answer correct for my profile reputations.

Comment: I was trying it thanks bro, I knew its that simple but my brain stopped working :) marked and upvoted.

Comment: Welcome, in coding it do happen, brain got stucked.

Answer (score 0):

you could use regex conditions for the url and based on that you can do if coniditions for the various social media links.